# onAfterFileDelete event for Webix uploader

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dom-events, webix

Working with the [Webix uploader](http://docs.webix.com/api__refs__ui.uploader.html), but unfortunately I'm unavailable to find `onAfterFileDelete` or `onAfterDelete` (or any) event. Something opposite to `onAfterFileAdd` would be very useful.

Here's **[a snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/b43f4c25)** of my attempts:

```
{ 
  view: "uploader", id:"upl1",
  autosend:false, value: 'Upload file',
  link:"uplist",  upload:"some.php",
  on:{        
    onAfterFileAdd:function(){
      console.log("onAfterFileAdd") // works well
    },
    onAfterFileDelete:function(){ // onAfterDelete? anything else?
      console.log("onAfterFileDelete")
    }
  }
},
{
  view:"list",  id:"uplist",  
  type:"uploader", autoheight:true, borderless:true           
}
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use uploader.files, which is an instance of DataCollection and has all necessary events.

```
$$("uplist").files.attachEvent("onBeforeDelete", handler)
```

http://docs.webix.com/api__refs__datacollection_events.html